# window.open() doesn't work correctly inside a JS function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried to create an updates list for my web, so that when I click on the relevant update- a new additional small html window will open and I will see the full update content.
This is the code I wrote:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p ng-controller="updatesCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="x in updates">
        <a href="updateWindow.html" onclick="showUpdate(x.title,x.update)">&#9679; {{x.title}}</a>
        <br><br>
    </span>                 
</p>

<script>updates();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
function updates(){
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('updatesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.updates = [
        {title:"update1",update:"update1 content"},
        {title:"update2",update:"update2 content"}
        ];
    });
}

function showUpdate(title, update){ 
    var win=window.open('updateWindow.html','newwindow','width=600, height=350'); 
    win.document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=title;
    win.document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=update;
    return false;
}
```

updateWindow.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="title"></h1>
<p id="update"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have few problems here:
1.When I clicked on the update link, the update window replaced the main page (index.html) window, and also was a full size page.
2. No change was made in the `<h1>` and the `<p>` of the updateWindow- although I wrote a script that was suppose to enter an html content to those places.

I don't understand why I didn't get what I expected with this code. Especially, I don't understand the first problem: if I only try to replace the `onclick` content inside `index.html` with this: `"window.open('updateWindow.html','newwindow','width=600, height=350'); return false;"` - I get a new additional window with a smaller size as expected (I won't get the update content inside this window, but at least that solves my first problem).

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Any reason you're using onclick instead of ng-click?

Comment: It doesn't work with ng-click as well as onclick (tried it now).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `window.open('updateWindow.html','_blank','width=600, height=350');` instead

Comment: Tnx. That solved my first problem- I now get a new additional small window. But I still have the second problem- the window is being opened without any content (the '<h1>' and '<p>' in it doesn't get content)

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that the window is not loading before you try to update html:
[image: Screenshot of my recreation]
you can see that the html page has not even loaded yet and the dev tools says there is a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` try getting the new page to update it `onload`in the update page.

Comment: You should have edited your first answer rather than posting second one

Comment: Ok, I tried doing it but didn't succedd. Can you please show how can you do it?

Comment: Add an onload tag to the body of updateWindow.html that updates the two things you want to update. you can use [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store them and then get them back in the new HTML